# Do xc:provisioning profile for iTunes connect to upload build?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes

I have knowledge about the app Store build submission and my app is available on iTunes. Now I want to update build. 
I have prepared iPhone build and try to submit to iTunes Connect via application Loader. But I got an error.
Should I prepare build by using XC: provisioning profile?

Please suggest me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *But I got an error* what kind of error ?

Comment: Do you expect a Yes or No answer? if no, what's the error you faced? and what's steps you did to get it?

Comment: YES or NO for make sure before resubmitting build.